# Python: addition of function in a for loop

Tags: python, function, for-loop, function-call

Dear python Stackoverflow users,

I want to add gaussian functions in a loop as it can be done with integer with the += sign. But I have no idea how to reasign a function value within a loop.

I have tried something like:

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

def f(x):
    return 0

for i in xdata:
    f(x) = f(x) + gaussian(x,i,20)
```

But I obtained the message "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call"

How could I make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: not sure to understand the output you want, could you give us some example?  
Or did you mean:
result = 0
result += gaussian(x,i,20)?

Comment: Replace `f(x)` in your code by `y` and replace `def f(x): return 0` by `y = 0`.

Comment: Ok, it works! Then a function can be defined only with a letter, without mentioning the variable!

Comment: @Damdamien no, you are defining a variable, which can store values.
Maybe you should read some basic programming courses to get a basic idea of how it works ;)

Comment: The syntax you were using there looks similar to the syntax you'd use to define a lambda. Normal function definitions look like your original definition of f and gaussian.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment:

> Replace `f(x)` in your code by `y` and replace `def f(x): return 0` by `y = 0`.

You replied:

> Ok, it works! Then a function can be defined only with a letter, without mentioning the variable!

That’s not really what’s going on. You are not defining a function. Your desired use of `f(x)` is not a function. The function `f` you defined does only one thing:

```
def f (x):
    return 0
```

The function will *always* return `0`. Once the function is defined like that, it cannot be changed (without replacing it by another function).

What you want to do is collect a function *result*—but not the result of `f` but the result of `gaussian`. Or actually, you want to collect all the results of the `gaussian` function calls and sum them up.

So what you do is create a variable which you add your results to, which as such represents the sum of those function calls.

Comment: Ok, then the variable y in our example depend of the other variable x, isn't it ? It is mathematically a function but not a python function.

Comment: `y` is just a variable; it does not have any functional dependencies. In order to have it depend on some value, you have to actively change it. That’s [imperative programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming): You tell the variable to change.

Answer (score 1):

f(x) return a result, so it is as you say 0 = 12, for example... That will throw an error, because '=' is assignment operator, so at left of it, you should only have a variable (or a constant for first assignment...).

So maybe you wanted  to do:

```
y = f(x) + gaussian(x,i,20)
```

But I don't want why you want to do a "+=", because it is only for variables... And your function always returns 0. So you might just say, instead of

```
def f(x):
    return 0
```

simply

```
y = 0
```

and then, tell after in the loop

```
y += gaussian(x, i, 20).
```

Or if you want to build a curve, you can use an array.

There is also an other error: 
x IS NOT DEFINED in your loop (defined in two functions, but only as local vars)

Answer (score 1):

```
def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    return np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

y = sum(gaussian(x, i, 20) for i in xdata)
```